# What represents 'StartupWMClass' entry from a .desktop file in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, desktop-application, ubuntu-unity

I am very new in developing application under Linux.

I have a doubt regarding about the use of **.desktop** file to add an icon into the Ubuntu Unity toolbar.

I have the following .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
#Exec=/usr/share/ConnectDataSpace/appl/launcher.sh
Exec=/usr/share/XCloud/appl/launcher.sh
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
#Name[en_US]=Connect Data Space
Name[en_US]=XCloud
#Name=Connect Data Space
Name=XCloud
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
#StartupWMClass=ConnectDataSpace
StartupWMClass=XCloud
#Icon=/usr/share/ConnectDataSpace/img/icoLauncher.png
Icon=/usr/share/XCloud/img/icoLauncher.png
```

My doubt is: What exactly represents the **StartupWMClass=XCloud** field of this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `StartupWMClass` - If specified, it is known that the application will
>   map at least one window with the given string as its WM class or WM
>   name hint (see the [Startup Notification Protocol Specification](http://www.freedesktop.org/Standards/startup-notification-spec) for
>   more details).

Source: [Recognized desktop entry keys](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html)

Comment: mmm it still a litle obscure for me...so if I specify the value of this field what exactly happen in my toolbar?

Comment: @AndreaNobili It does not happen something specific (what you can see it). Think as that WM class  or WM name is like a hint to detect an opened window (see, for example `man xprop` or `man wmctrl`). So, it can be used to customize window matching. Here is an example: http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=How_to_Customize_Window_Matching.